# How to use the data from a function in another script?

Tags: python

What I am trying to do is execute a function and be able to take the data of the variables that that function offers me.

Here is an example of my code:

```
# test.py
def display(var1,var2):
    sum = var1+var2
    print(sum)
```

---

```
# main.py
from test import *
display(1,2)
print(sum)
```

You can see that from the `main.py` file I try to call the function to add the numbers 1+2 **(that works perfectly)** and print the sum result **(in this I have problems)**. How do I get the value of that variable without printing it from `test.py`?

Comment: Let's don't use builtin `sum` as variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `return` to pass a value back to the caller, which you can then assign to a variable (be careful about using `sum` as a variable name, as that overwrites the built-in function in the location where you do that):

```
# test.py
def sum_values(var1, var2):
  return var1 + var2

# main.py
from test import *
summed = sum_values(1,2)
print(summed)
```

I renamed the `display` function to `sum_values` since it no longer displays a value, but returns the summed value instead.